# Apache rewrite rules error

Tags: apache2, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Some rules are working properly, and everything is properly set up in the conf files to allow rewrites to work correctly But some rules are failing or may be the url string doesnot reach that rule and is already redirected.

Like for this rule--

```
RewriteRule coach/(.*)$ coach.php?coach=$1
```

If i call url -> `localhost/coach/fitness` tt gets redirected to `localhost/coach.php` and no get param is received in the php file.

Now if I change this rule to

```
RewriteRule coach/(.*)$ cp.php?coach=$1
```

and also change the file name from *coach.php* in my dir to *cp.php* Then it works perfectly fine for the given url and get param is received.

So the problem is if the file with url string name exists it gets redirected to that file only and no redirection rules are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Use following at the top of your `.htaccess` file

```
# Options -Multiviews #
```